# Convert HTML to PDF in MVC with iTextSharp in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, itext, html-to-pdf

I am trying to convert HTML to PDF with `iTextSharp` in MVC Razor, but everything I have tried has not worked. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a detailed and [`step-by-step tutorial`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66948/Rendering-PDF-views-in-ASP-MVC-using-iTextSharp) on CodeProject you might follow. It illustrates how you could serve an ASP.NET MVC View as PDF file using iTextSharp for the conversion. Bear in mind though that iTextSharp was not meant for converting HTML to PDF so it might not cope very well with complex HTML pages and CSS styles.

Comment: I want to know that if iTextSharp was not meant for converting HTML to PDF, which one with free source?

Comment: IF TODAY DATE >14.07.2015 DO NOT LOOK TO THIS ANSWER!

Comment: @MDDDC why not? Where should I look then?

Comment: This step by step tutorial is not "Razor". It is aspx, web forms... It is not up to date.

Answer (score 34):

Here is how you implement this solution using the **Razor** engine **NOT** with the weird `<itext..` markup.

This way you have full control over the pdf presentation using standard html output.

The project with an example solution and source code is available here with nuget installation instructions:

https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf

```
Install-Package MvcRazorToPdf
```

This also uses the new itextsharp licence, so does not suffer from any of the negatives mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: Man, you rock, thanks. Can i change the page orientation somehow?

Comment: @EdgarSalazar No problem. As it uses the iTextXmlWorker underneath, I think you should be able to resolve this by styling a div to your landscape proportions.

Comment: @sports yes, table example here: https://github.com/andyhutch77/MvcRazorToPdf/blob/master/MvcRazorToPdfExample/Views/Pdf/Index.cshtml

Comment: this dll does not support culture specific characters

Answer (score 4):

You should check out [RazorPDF](http://www.nyveldt.com/blog/post/Introducing-RazorPDF) which is using iText to generate the PDF, but in a friendlier way.

Comment: Hi Rosdi Kasim. Appearantly the latest iTextSharp version (5.4.4) is not working properly with RazorPDF and has rendered it useless.

Comment: @real_yggdrasil Be careful.. latest iTextSharp (starting from 5.x) has different license. Also 'rendered useless' is not helpful.. try submit your question with some example or detailed description..

Comment: I disagree. It has been rendered useless in that it does nothing and has not been updated since 2012.

Answer (score 4):

```
public virtual void printpdf(string html)    
{
     String htmlText = html.ToString();
     Document document = new Document();
     string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Pdf/");
     PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(filePath + "\\pdf-"+Filename+".pdf", FileMode.Create));

     document.Open();    
     iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);       
     hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));    
     document.Close();    
}
```

just pass `html string` in to parameter 
that string you will get by renderpartialview `text = viewname....`

Answer (score 2):

A good way to convert from MVC HTML View to PDF (even if it's not directly on the subject regarding iTextSharp) is using [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/) :

```
Install-Package Rotativa
```

This is based on `wkhtmltopdf` but it has better css support than iTextSharp has and is very simple to integrate with MVC as you can simply return the view as pdf:

```
public ActionResult GetPdf()
{
    //...
    return new ViewAsPdf(model);// and you are done!
}
```

Comment: I worked with Rotativa , it works based on popup and need to unblock popup blocker. Moreover after use ViewAsPdf or ActionAsPdf all Sessions will be cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example for MVC Razor in C# using the [evo html to pdf for .net](http://www.evopdf.com/) to convert the current MVC view to PDF and send the resulted PDF to browser for download:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConvertCurrentPageToPdf(FormCollection collection)
{
    object model = null;
    ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

    // The string writer where to render the HTML code of the view
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    // Render the Index view in a HTML string
    ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "Index", null);
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
            ControllerContext,
            viewResult.View,
            viewData,
            new TempDataDictionary(),
            stringWriter
            );
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);

    // Get the view HTML string
    string htmlToConvert = stringWriter.ToString();

    // Get the base URL
    String currentPageUrl = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    String baseUrl = currentPageUrl.Substring(0, currentPageUrl.Length - "Convert_Current_Page/ConvertCurrentPageToPdf".Length);

    // Create a HTML to PDF converter object with default settings
    HtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

    // Convert the HTML string to a PDF document in a memory buffer
    byte[] outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(htmlToConvert, baseUrl);

    // Send the PDF file to browser
    FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(outPdfBuffer, "application/pdf");
    fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Convert_Current_Page.pdf";

    return fileResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can find a different approach in case you want to write plain xml, i find it much simpler and lighter.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it using `MVC`:

```
[Route("ABCDD")]
[HttpGet]
public void ABCDD() {
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    // string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    string url = "http://localhost:3042/Reports/COAListing";
    string fileContent = wc.DownloadString(url);

    List<string> tableContents = GetContents(fileContent, table_pattern);

    string HTMLString = String.Join(" ", tableContents.ToArray());

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Welcome to dotnetfox"));
    List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTMLString), null);
    for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++) {
        pdfDoc.Add((IElement) htmlarraylist[k]);
    }

    pdfDoc.Close();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" +
            "filename=sample.pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Your answer uses `HTMLWorker`, which is deprecated. You should use `XMLWorker`.

Comment: it giving error XMLWorker does not exist in current Context

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? Can you reproduce it in iTextSharp 5.5.9?

Comment: Yes its iTextSharp 5.5.9

Comment: Can you reproduce it in iText 7.1.2 + pdfHTML?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using ASP.NET Core and iTextSharp is not that important to you here is my solution using PhantomJS: http://nikolay.it/Blog/2018/03/Generate-PDF-file-from-Razor-view-using-ASP-NET-Core-and-PhantomJS/37

### Get HTML string from a Razor view

This step is pretty straight-forward. There is a service called `IRazorViewEngine` in ASP.NET Core which can be injected and then used to get the view. After providing the view with default `ViewDataDictionary` and `ActionContext` we can request the view to be rendered into `StringWriter` which can be easily converted to string. Here is ready-to-use code for getting a string from given Razor view file:

```
public interface IViewRenderService
{
    Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model);
}

public class ViewRenderService : IViewRenderService
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public ViewRenderService(
        IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        this.tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = this.serviceProvider };
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = this.razorViewEngine.GetView(null, viewName, false);

            if (viewResult.View == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
            }

            var viewDictionary =
                new ViewDataDictionary(
                    new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    new ModelStateDictionary()) { Model = model };

            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, this.tempDataProvider),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions());

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

One important think here: if you use view compilation (pre-compiling views to `YourProject.Web.PrecompiledViews.dll`) then it is important to get the view using the `GetView` method instead of `FindView`. More information [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/issues/191#issuecomment-324435628).

### Generate the PDF file from HTML using PhantomJS

For this task we are going to use a headless browser which will render the HTML (with all CSS and JS included in it). There are many such tools but I will use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API). PhantomJS can save the rendered page to small-sized PDF pretty fast. For the PDF export to work we are going to need a `.js` file which will use the PhantomJS API to tell the tool that we want to export the file:

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address,
    output;

console.log('Usage: rasterize.js [URL] [filename] [paperformat]');
address = system.args[1];
output = system.args[2];
page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
page.paperSize = { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '0.5cm' };

page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

The next thing is to run the `phantomjs.exe` process and pass the `rasterize.js` file along with paths for the HTML file and the output file name for the PDF result. This is done in `HtmlToPdfConverter.cs`:

```
public interface IHtmlToPdfConverter
{
    byte[] Convert(string htmlCode);
}

public class HtmlToPdfConverter : IHtmlToPdfConverter
{
    public byte[] Convert(string htmlCode)
    {
        var inputFileName = "input.html";
        var outputFileName = "output.pdf";
        File.WriteAllText(inputFileName, htmlCode);
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("phantomjs.exe")
                            {
                                WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                                Arguments = string.Format(
                                    "rasterize.js \"{0}\" {1} \"A4\"",
                                    inputFileName,
                                    outputFileName),
                                UseShellExecute = true,
                            };

        var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        process.Start();

        process.WaitForExit();

        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(outputFileName);

        File.Delete(inputFileName);
        File.Delete(outputFileName);

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

If you are going to deploy your application in Azure it is important to have `UseShellExecute` set to `true`.

### Use the code together

Since we now have implemented both `IViewRenderService` and `IHtmlToPdfConverter` we can start using them by first register them in the `Startup.cs` file where your ConfigureServices method should be located (`services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>()` and `services.AddScoped<IHtmlToPdfConverter, HtmlToPdfConverter>()`). Now lets see the code wrapped up together:

```
private readonly IViewRenderService viewRenderService;
private readonly IHtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter;

public DashboardController(
    IViewRenderService viewRenderService,
    IHtmlToPdfConverter htmlToPdfConverter)
{
    this.viewRenderService = viewRenderService;
    this.htmlToPdfConverter = htmlToPdfConverter;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPdf(SomeInputModel input)
{
    var model = this.GetViewModel(input);
    var htmlData = await this.viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("~/Views/Dashboard/GetPdf.cshtml", model);
    var fileContents = this.htmlToPdfConverter.Convert(htmlData);
    return this.File(fileContents, "application/pdf");
}
```