# website using iTextSharp needs to save PDF on local machine C drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, itext

I'm trying to have iTextSharp create a PDF file of the web page and save it to the users computer C drive.  This works in debug but when I publish it to the server files never get saved on the computer but the application is saying that it did save it.  I think I need to set my path differently. This is in MVC4 C#.

```
var pdfDoc = new Document();

const string folderPath = "C:\\SG-ListingPDFs\\";

bool isExists = Directory.Exists(folderPath);

if (!isExists)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);


var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("C:\\SG-ListingPDFs\\" + detailsViewModel.ListingNumber + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
                pdfDoc.Open();

//Code here

pdfDoc.Add(table);

TempData["SavedPdF"] = true;
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: does the web server have permission to write to that path?

Comment: I've created a library that you can use to do this, might be of some use to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517171/convert-html-to-pdf-in-mvc-with-itextsharp-in-mvc-razor/20198939#20198939 Does not save to disc but sends to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No web server technology has the ability to save a file directly the users computer.  What you would need to do is save the file to the server (which you are doing now) and then send a download to the users browser.

To do that in asp.net mvc..

```
public FileResult GetFile()
{
    byte[] filebytes;

    //load file data however you please
    return File(filebytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

If you dont want want to save the file to the local disk, you could also generate your pdf in memory and send it straight out.

[Create PDF in memory instead of physical file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815761/create-pdf-in-memory-instead-of-physical-file)

Comment: I see, this makes sense. I am  new to this so I don't understand your code but I do have questions for you.  If the files are being stored on the server first does that mean server will run out of space eventually? I see how to create the PDF in memory but it's the end peace that I don't understand, how do you save the inmemory PDF?  Can you show me a more elaborative code?

Comment: An in memory file is pushed out to the browser, if the user wishes to save it as a physical file they can choose to via the browser.