# Open save as window with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

Is there a way to open the save as window when saving webpage to PDF using iTextSharp? right now I'm just saving it to a set file.

```
var pdfDoc = new Document();

const string folderPath = "C:\\SG-ListingPDFs\\";

bool isExists = Directory.Exists(folderPath);

if (!isExists)
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("C:\\SG-ListingPDFs\\" + detailsViewModel.ListingNumber + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
pdfDoc.Open();

....Code Here

pdfDoc.Add(table);

TempData["SavedPdF"] = true;
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: I've created a razor html to pdf library that may be of use to you too. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517171/convert-html-to-pdf-in-mvc-with-itextsharp-in-mvc-razor/20198939#20198939

Comment: instead of asking the same question more than once, I'd suggest you do some research on this topic then come back if you run into a specific problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245553/website-using-itextsharp-needs-to-save-pdf-on-local-machine-c-drive

Comment: They are two different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create the stream as a referenced variable i.e.

```
var aFileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", detailsViewModel.ListingNumber + "pdf";
var aStream =  new FileStream("C:\\SG-ListingPDFs\\" + aFileName);
```

Then pass it into the get instance like this:

```
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, aStream , FileMode.Create));
```

Then from your controller return the stream like this as a `FileResult`.

```
public ActionResult SaveFile()
{   
    // processing to get the file etc....

    return File(filePath, aStream , aFileName);
}
```

The important part in the above is the `aFileName` paramater, this is the `fileNameDownload` parameter which makes it open as a downloadable file.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have an `ActionResult` method that returns a file and set the appropriate request headers.

```
public ActionResult Pdf()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=YourFile.pdf");
    return File(yourPdfFile, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

`File()` has a few overloads that take either a `byte[]`, a `System.IO.Stream` or the path to an actual file on disk. I'm not too familiar with iTextSharp so I can't help you much further, but this should send you on the right track.

If my memory serves me right, the header is needed in a specific browser (I'm thinking IE) to get the save as dialog to pop.